# Run Method when Preference is Updated

Tags: android

How would I add a listener so that when a preference is changed (i.e. CheckBoxPreference) some 
method is executed (i.e. Toast)

Preferences.java

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


}

}
```

Main.java

```
[...]
SharedPreferences preferences;
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AdvancedPreferences.html